# Same query in stored procedure and anonymous block gives different results

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, anonymous-methods

The **stored procedure** (in Oracle)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_OBJ_COUNT
AS
BEGIN
    FOR v_record IN (SELECT OWNER, COUNT(*) NUM_OBJ FROM ALL_OBJECTS GROUP BY OWNER ORDER BY OWNER)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('***DEBUG***: Schema: '||v_record.OWNER||', Obj count:'||v_record.NUM_OBJ);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

gives the following result

```
***DEBUG***: Schema: ORACLE_OCM, Obj count:2
***DEBUG***: Schema: DBCONTROL, Obj count:27
***DEBUG***: Schema: PUBLIC, Obj count:22543
***DEBUG***: Schema: SCH_PRIV, Obj count:11
***DEBUG***: Schema: SYS, Obj count:22332
***DEBUG***: Schema: SYSTEM, Obj count:5
***DEBUG***: Schema: XDB, Obj count:181
```

If I run the same code as **anonymous block**

```
BEGIN
    FOR v_record IN (SELECT OWNER, COUNT(*) NUM_OBJ FROM ALL_OBJECTS GROUP BY OWNER ORDER BY OWNER)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('***DEBUG***: Schema: '||v_record.OWNER||', Obj count:'||v_record.NUM_OBJ);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I get different result (which I guess is accurate)

```
***DEBUG***: Schema: APPQOSSYS, Obj count:3
***DEBUG***: Schema: DBSNMP, Obj count:55
***DEBUG***: Schema: ORACLE_OCM, Obj count:8
***DEBUG***: Schema: DBCONTROL, Obj count:27
***DEBUG***: Schema: OUTLN, Obj count:8
***DEBUG***: Schema: PUBLIC, Obj count:22543
***DEBUG***: Schema: SCH_PRIV, Obj count:43
***DEBUG***: Schema: SYS, Obj count:29321
***DEBUG***: Schema: SYSTEM, Obj count:501
***DEBUG***: Schema: TEST_SYAM_123, Obj count:3
***DEBUG***: Schema: XDB, Obj count:474
```

Why does it happen?

Why the *stored procedure* unable to locate some schemas?

How do we get the accurate values using *stored procedure*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because privileges granted to a user by role are not available for the stored procedure.

More on this here: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-roles-in-oracle-stored-procedures/